# Arquivos externos na main em C (#include)

Tags: c

Tenho o seguinte código:

main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "LSE.h"
```

E mais dos arquivos:

- LSE.h onde defino a struct de uma lista simplesmente encadeada e o protótipo das suas funções.
- LSE.c onde implemento as funções definidas no LSE.h e uso `#include "LSE.h"` para linkar tudo.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte: na main o correto é fazer `#include "LSE.h"` ou `#include "LSE.c"`. Se eu faço da primeira forma o programa funciona corretamente compilando pelo cmd, mas não funciona ao compilar pelo Visual Studio Code (extensão C/C++ Compile Run). Já se faço da segunda forma, acontece o contrário, não compila pelo cmd e compila pelo VSCode.

---

Erro VSCode (com `#include "LSE.h"` na main):

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQaZIye.o:main.c:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `criaLista'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQaZIye.o:main.c:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `insereInicio'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQaZIye.o:main.c:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `insereFim'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQaZIye.o:main.c:(.text+0xee): undefined reference to `insereMeio'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQaZIye.o:main.c:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to `imprime'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQaZIye.o:main.c:(.text+0x131): undefined reference to `destroi'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQaZIye.o:main.c:(.text+0x14d): undefined reference to `imprime'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Erro cmd (com `#include "LSE.c"` na main):

```
C:\Users\joaor\Documents\UFRGS\Estruturas de Dados\Laboratórios\Lab 03\Nova pasta>gcc -c main.c

C:\Users\joaor\Documents\UFRGS\Estruturas de Dados\Laboratórios\Lab 03\Nova pasta>gcc -c LSE.c

C:\Users\joaor\Documents\UFRGS\Estruturas de Dados\Laboratórios\Lab 03\Nova pasta>gcc -o main LSE.c main.c
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFcs4lF.o:main.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `criaLista'; C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\cciH1VOU.o:LSE.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFcs4lF.o:main.c:(.text+0xa): multiple definition of `tamanho'; C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\cciH1VOU.o:LSE.c:(.text+0xa): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFcs4lF.o:main.c:(.text+0x3e): multiple definition of `insereInicio'; C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\cciH1VOU.o:LSE.c:(.text+0x3e): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFcs4lF.o:main.c:(.text+0x6f): multiple definition of `insereMeio'; C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\cciH1VOU.o:LSE.c:(.text+0x6f): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFcs4lF.o:main.c:(.text+0xfe): multiple definition of `insereFim'; C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\cciH1VOU.o:LSE.c:(.text+0xfe): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFcs4lF.o:main.c:(.text+0x163): multiple definition of `imprime'; C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\cciH1VOU.o:LSE.c:(.text+0x163): first defined here
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\ccFcs4lF.o:main.c:(.text+0x1b8): multiple definition of `destroi'; C:\Users\joaor\AppData\Local\Temp\cciH1VOU.o:LSE.c:(.text+0x1b8): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Compila e executa normalmente se eu usar `#include "LSE.h"` para compilar no cmd ou `#include "LSE.c"` para compilar pelo VSCode. Qual é a utilização correta? O que fazer para resolver e usar apenas uma forma para ambas compilações?

Comment: Essa é a construção comum. Apenas inclua o header em todos os programas que usam as funções de LSE.c, e passe o código já compilado de LSE.c como a entrada para o linker. Em geral se tem _unresolved reference_ para alguma função é porque esqueceu do header e se tem _multiple definition_ ;e porque esqueceu de usar um _include guard_  ou uma diretiva tipo _ #pragma once_

Comment: No VS Code aprenda como incluir na compilação todos os fontes do projeto, editando o build task. Ou use uma ferramenta como o CMake que funciona muito bem com VS Code